# Send a JSON as payload via MQTT to Fiware

Tags: json, fiware, payload

I am working on this Fiware flow:

[image: Fiware flow]

I can successfully send MQTT messages to the `iotagent-ul` using the mqtt paho library. E.g. a single type message through the publish library:

```
publish.single("/ul/5jggokgpepnvsb2uv4s40d59ov/agv001/attrs", "AGV_Th|25|AVG_X|0.35", hostname="172.31.85.246", port=31624)
```

However, I would need to send JSON payloads, is it possible to send this message format through `iotagent-ul` or would it be necessary to use another iot agent like `iotagent-json` as an interpreter for these messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [IoT Agent for Ultralight](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-ul) accepts payloads using the MIME type `text/plain` and parses Ultralight payloads like this - it is just a string of ASCII characters separated by `|`

```
t|3|x|4
```

The [IoT Agent for JSON](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-json) accepts payloads using the MIME type `application/json` and parses JSON payloads like this:

```json
{"t": 3, "x": 4}
```

You would need to use the  IoT Agent for JSON to parse JSON payloads. Both Ultralight and JSON Agents support the same set of transports (HTTP, MQTT and AMPQ)